# How do you create a file in assembly with a dynamically specified file path?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls

This question is mainly how to handle the pathname which is an arbitrarily long string, in assembly, without `db` or any helpers like that. I have seen several examples such as [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_file_management.htm) which shows:

```
section .text
   global _start         ;must be declared for using gcc

_start:                  ;tell linker entry point
   ;create the file
   mov  eax, 8
   mov  ebx, file_name
   mov  ecx, 0777        ;read, write and execute by all
   int  0x80             ;call kernel

   section  .data
file_name db 'myfile.txt'
```

However, I would specifically like to understand how to do this *dynamically*. I would like to (1) better understand the requirements of the filename in terms of assembly (does it need a null terminator, etc.), and more importantly (2) specify the file name *without* the use of `db` or any assembler helpers. For example, you could specify the file name through the command line, and its structure would be unknown to the object file.

How do you do this?

Comment: (1) yes the string needs a null terminator (2) has little to do with creating a file, more with accessing arguments.

Comment: Unrelated to the filename, but your file mode is wrong because a `0` prefix doesn't mean octal to nasm. See [How to represent octal numbers in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39564402/7509065) for the right way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**System calls that take a `const char*` without a length arg always take C strings: 0-terminated, implicit length**.

Like `open(const char *path, int flags, int mode)`, unlike `write(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)`.

This is why they work when called from C like `open("input.txt", O_RDONLY)`, or `open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT)`.  Remember that C string literals give you a pointer to an array of `char` in static storage with a `0` terminator.

BTW, NULL is a pointer constant.  NUL is ASCII `'\0'`.  Just call them "`0` terminated" strings.

---

So yes, you should use `, 0` at the end of your `db`.

**Command-line args are always in this C-string format; it's how Unix passes around string data across system-call / process boundaries,** as well as to ISO C standard library functions.  This includes all pathnames.

---

In Linux, on entry to `_start`, the stack pointer points at `argc`.  Above that are the elements of the `char *argv[]` array.  (Not a `char **argv` pointer, just an array of values right there on the stack, from ESP+4 to ESP+argc*4.  Also terminated by a NULL pointer (`0`)).  This is documented in the i386 and x86-64 System V ABI docs.

[Linux Assembly x86_64 create a file using command line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071711/linux-assembly-x86-64-create-a-file-using-command-line-parameters) shows an example of loading `argv[1]` into the `pathname` arg of a system call.

[Reading from a file in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347747/reading-from-a-file-in-assembly) is a 32-bit example.

Answer (score 1):

Just build the string in memory somehow (with a null terminator, as was pointed out in the comments), and then pass the pointer to it in place of `file_name`. To use a command-line argument, it's already built for you, so just point to it, like this: `mov  ebx, [esp + 8]` (for reference, that's equivalent to `argv[1]`). By the way, in a real program, you should check `argc` (which lives at `[esp]`) before you do that to make sure it's at least 2.

Comment: How does it know to use the null pointer, is that in the Intel docs somewhere?